# Is there a reason I am unable to specify the start offset of a Rust program in a linker script?

Tags: assembly, rust, linker, arm64, linker-scripts

I am trying to compile a Rust program for a Raspberry Pi. I am under the impression that the start address needs to be `0x8000`, so I am using a custom linker script to lay out the program to follow this requirement:

```
SECTIONS
{
  .text 0x8000 : {
    *(.text)
  }

  .data : {
    *(.data)
  }
}
```

I specify this in the architecture file `aarch64-unknown-none.json`:

```json
{
  "arch": "aarch64",
  "data-layout": "e-m:e-i8:8:32-i16:16:32-i64:64-i128:128-n32:64-S128",
  "disable-redzone": true,
  "executables": true,
  "features": "+strict-align,+neon,+fp-armv8",
  "linker": "rust-lld",
  "linker-flavor": "ld.lld",
  "pre-link-args": {
    "ld.lld": [
      "-Taarch64-raspi3.ld"
    ]
  },
  "llvm-target": "aarch64-unknown-none",
  "max-atomic-width": 128,
  "panic-strategy": "abort",
  "relocation-model": "static",
  "target-pointer-width": "64",
  "unsupported-abis": [
    "stdcall",
    "stdcall-unwind",
    "fastcall",
    "vectorcall",
    "thiscall",
    "thiscall-unwind",
    "win64",
    "sysv64"
  ]
}
```

I build using the `cargo build -Zbuild-std --features=raspi3 --target=aarch64-unknown-none.json --release` command.

Here is my `main.rs`:

```rust
#![cfg_attr(not(test), no_std)]
#![cfg_attr(not(test), no_main)]
#![feature(global_asm)]
#![feature(asm)]
#![feature(naked_functions)]

#[cfg(not(test))]
global_asm!(include_str!("platform/raspi3/start.s"));

mod aarch64;
mod panic;
mod platform;
```

Here is `start.s`:

```
.section .init
.global _start

.equ BASE,  0x3f200000 //Base address
.equ GPFSEL2, 0x08          //FSEL2 register offset 
.equ GPSET0,  0x1c          //GPSET0 register offset
.equ GPCLR0,0x28            //GPCLR0 register offset
.equ SET_BIT3,   0x08       //sets bit three b1000      
.equ SET_BIT21,  0x200000   //sets bit 21
.equ COUNTER, 0xf0000

_start:
    ldr x0, =BASE
    ldr x1, =SET_BIT3
    str x1, [x0, #GPFSEL2]
    ldr x1, =SET_BIT21
    str x1, [x0, #GPSET0]
    b _start
```

When I compile it, it places the start block at 0x0 as follows:

```
0000000000000000 <_start>:
   0:   d2a7e400        mov     x0, #0x3f200000                 // #1059061760
   4:   d2800101        mov     x1, #0x8                        // #8
   8:   f9000401        str     x1, [x0, #8]
   c:   d2a00401        mov     x1, #0x200000                   // #2097152
  10:   f801c001        stur    x1, [x0, #28]
  14:   17fffffb        b       0 <_start>
```

Is there a reason that this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write:

```
.text 0x8000 : {
    *(.text)
  }
```

you are telling the linker to set up the excutable `.text` section at address `0x8000`, by concatenating the `.text` sections from every compilation module (`*`).

But then, in your assembly, the `_start` function is defined in the `.section .init`, that is not mentioned anywhere in the linker script. I'm not sure of what happens exactly with sections that are not mentioned in the linker script, but I'm pretty sure it is a bad idea to rely on that.

You probably want your `.init` section(s) to be at the start of the executable `.text` section:

```
  .text 0x8000 : {
    *(.init) /* _start */
    *(.text)
  }
```

NOTE: AFAIK, Rust does not emit all the code into a big `.text` section, but it creates a lot smaller `.text.name_of_the_thing` sections. You'll probably want to link them all of them together so:

```
  .text 0x8000 : {
    *(.init) /* _start */
    *(.text)
    *(.text.*)
  }
```

Comment: I think sections that aren't mentioned don't become part of the linker output at all.

Comment: @PeterCordes: That's what I thought, but the OP does get `_start` into the executable be without mentioning its section, and I reproduced it. It ended up in a `.init` section in the exe. My guess is that unmentioned sections are copied to an output section of the same name. But in what order?

Comment: I thought I remembered something like this coming up in other Q&As, but probably I'm misremembering what was written, or got the wrong idea somewhere.

Comment: @PeterCordes: From `info ld` that I guess it applies equally if you use a bogus `SECTIONS` (emphasis mine): _"If you do not use a `SECTIONS` command in your linker script, the linker will place each input section into **an identically named output section in the order that the sections are first encountered in the input files**.  If all input sections are present in the first file, for example, the order of sections in the output file will match the order in the first input file.  **The first section will be at address zero**."_